# How to install tensor flow on Linux

Tags: python, tensorflow

On the main TensorFlow website, you must specifically enable the gpu:

```
# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled:
$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp34-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

---

On the anaconda website, you only have to install tensor flow, but there is no indication whether this is the GPU or CPU version:

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/jjhelmus tensorflow
```

---

After running the Anaconda command, I decided that I needed to make sure that it was the GPU version, so I tried to run the pip command inside the anaconda folder.

When I ran the pip command, I got the following error:

> tensorflow-0.7.1-cp34-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

---

I have no idea what a wheel is...but I have a newish laptop with a multicore i7 (July last year) and a laptop nvidia card with a compute rating of 5.2 and CUDA installed (Ubuntu 15.10).

There must be a version that is compatible with my specs.

How do I upgrade my tensor flow install to the GPU version?

**Update**

When I run: `import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())`, the supported wheels include

> cp35

But the wheel that is available for TensorFlow is cp34...so does that mean TensorFlow on the GPU does not work for my computer?

Comment: Have you tried running `pip3 install --upgrade pip` first?

Comment: ok, just did...still looks like it only accepts cp35.  could that be a number that is relevant to my particular machine?

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, but one thing you could try is retrieving the wheel and renaming it to cp35 prior to running the pip3 install.  (Apparently some people have had success with that approach for similar issues.)  Of course, it would be better to root cause the failure to the extent possible first.  What is the full command and output when you run the pip command?  Any exception info?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As dumb as it seems, just renaming the wheel from 3.4 to 3.5 is sufficient:

```
$ wget https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp34-none-linux_x86_64.whl
...
$ pip install tensorflow-0.7.1-cp34-none-linux_x86_64.whl
tensorflow-0.7.1-cp34-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
$ mv tensorflow-0.7.1-cp3{4,5}-none-linux_x86_64.whl
$ pip install tensorflow-0.7.1-cp35-none-linux_x86_64.whl
Processing ./tensorflow-0.7.1-cp35-none-linux_x86_64.whl
...
Installing collected packages: tensorflow
Successfully installed tensorflow-0.7.1
```

Comment: Might I add that for TF for Linux (`https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl`) you have to replace both the `cp34` with `cp35`.

Comment: Looks like there are now binaries for 3.5 as of tensorflow 0.9.0: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v0.9.0rc0

Answer (score 1):

Everything changed in Tensorflow V1.0 and This guide explains how to install TensorFlow on Ubuntu of Course with GPU supported.I have only tested these instructions on Ubuntu 14.04.

- ### nVidia Check

first of all you must check that nVidia installed for check this enter the command below:

```
nvidia-smi
```

and you should see somthing like this

[image]

if you see this your nvidia card is correctly installed.

- ### Install CUDA,Cudnn

go to https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads and download cuda toolkit for ubutu 14.04 (download .deb file) and install it with these commands

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

**Be Careful** tensorflow V1.0 is needed cuda-8.0 and is not worked with cuda-7.5 and if you have installed cuda-7.5 and lower , you got this error when import tensorflow in python

ImportError: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

after install cuda-8.0 go to https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn and download cuDNN v5.1 (Jan 20, 2017), for CUDA 8.0 and install with commands below

```
tar -xzvf cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v5.1.tgz
sudo cp -P include/cudnn.h /usr/local/include
sudo cp -P lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/lib64
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/lib64/libcudnn*
```

at the end add these lines to your path file maybe add these lines to ~/.bashrc file for doing this use these commands below:

open ~/.bashrc

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

add these lines

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-8.0
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

- ### Tensorflow

for installing tensorflow with gpu supported you can install it with one command below

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

> I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
>   I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
>   I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
>   I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
>   I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally

after all if do everythings right when you import tensorflow in python console you can see these and this means your tensorflow with gpu supported

Comment: Nice.  Will test out this weekend.